# Proof that sum of continuous functions is continuous in metric space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

**Definition**: A function $f: X \to Y$ between metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ is continuous in $x \in X$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x' \in X$ with $d(x,x') < \delta$:
$$
 d(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon.
$$
Now I want to proof that the sum of continuous functions at a point $x$ is continuous at that point $x$ by just using this definition (i.e. not using the limit criterion).

If the metric is induced by a norm, $d(x,y) := ||x-y||$ then this is easy.

Let $x \in X$ be fixed, $f = f_1 + f_2$ with $f_1, f_2$ being continuous at $x$. Then for $\varepsilon > 0$ let $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ be the Delta's for the functions $f_1, f_2$. Set $\delta := \operatorname{max}(\delta_1, \delta_2)$, then
\begin{align*}
 d(f(x), f(x')) & = d(f_1(x) + f_2(x), f_1(x') + f_2(x')) \\
                & = ||f_1(x) + f_2(x) - (f_1(x') + f_2(x')) \\
                & = ||f_1(x) - f_1(x') + f_2(x) - f_2(x')) \\
                & \le ||f_1(x) - f_1(x')|| + ||f_2(x) - f_2(x')|| \\
                & = d(f_1(x)),f_1(x')) + d(f_2(x), f_2(x')) \\
                & \le 2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
I want to generalize this proof for a metric, but therefore I needed the inequality
$$
 d(x+u, y+v) \le d(x,y) + d(u,v)
$$
which I is false, what I learned here:

[Does $d(x+u, y + v) \le d(x, y) + d(u,v)$ holds for every metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284478/does-dxu-y-v-le-dx-y-du-v-holds-for-every-metric)

But how does I proof it then for a metric space?

Comment: How do you define the sum of two functions between metric spaces?

Comment: you don't even have an addition operation; a metric space is not necessarily equipped with an addition

Comment: Are your functions defined from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ perhaps?

Comment: You should examine the metric spaces you work with more closely – what is addition in them? Then you could ask yourself whether $+ \colon Y × Y → Y$ is continous or not. If your metric spaces $X$, $Y$ happen to be complete, you can check this by finding out if the sum of convergent sequences in $Y$ happens to converge to the sum of their limits. Then this would imply the sum of continuous functions is continuous. Maybe you don't need $X$ to be complete for this argument.

Comment: ok, I undertand then there exists no addition in general. And what if i consider functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Stefan If $Y$ is a normed vector space (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$ with norm given by absolute value), then the computation you give above actually gives you want you want, except that you should have defined $\delta$ to be the minimum, not the maximum, of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, anyway. In the greatest possible generality, if $Y$ is just some topological abelian group, so that addition as a map $Y \times Y \to Y$ is continuous, then it is enough to show that the map $X \to Y \times Y$ given by $x \mapsto (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is continuous.